# EOS world state sharding

Tags: blockchains

What is the current plan to shard EOS blockchain state? (Different from transaction parallel processing).

As far as I understand currently all block producers need to store everything. When the state grows larger will this be still feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phase 4 - Parallel Optimization Summer / Fall 2018

Please refer to the following roadmap.
https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/Roadmap.md

In the white paper, you can see that shard is already included when planning the block structure.

These are applied for feasibility. See the following link. https://www.investinblockchain.com/eosio-dawn/

- Light Client Validation
- Sparse Header Verification

Comment: I think the part with inter-blockchain communication in the article answers to this. Parallel optimization is only running transactions for the same block in parallal AFAIK.